# How to Access / Read any Text / Tag Value from the Webpage using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing my First Chrome Plugin and I just want to get some text present on the current webpage and show it as a alert when i click the Extension. Lets say I am using any any webpage on www.google.com after some Search query, Google shows something like "About 1,21,00,00,000 results (0.39 seconds) " . I want to show this Text as an alert when i execute my plugin. This is what i am doing.

**here is the manifest.json that i am using**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Getting started example",
"description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
"version": "1.0",

"background": {
  "persistent": false,
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],
"js": ["content.js"]
}],

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"permissions": [
"activeTab"
]
}
```

**Here is my popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.getElementById("checkPage").addEventListener("click", handler);
});`

function handler() {
var a = document.getElementById("resultStats");
alert(a.innerText);  // or alert(a.innerHTML);
}
```

**Here is my content.js**

```
// Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
// If the received message has the expected format...
if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
    // Call the specified callback, passing
    // the web-page's DOM content as argument
    sendResponse(document.all[0].outerHTML);
}
});
```

**Here is my background.js**

```
var urlRegex = /^https?:\/\/(?:[^./?#]+\.)?google\.com/;

// A function to use as callback
function doStuffWithDom(domContent) {
    console.log('I received the following DOM content:\n' + domContent);
}

// When the browser-action button is clicked...
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // ...check the URL of the active tab against our pattern and...
    if (urlRegex.test(tab.url)) {
        // ...if it matches, send a message specifying a callback too
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {text: 'report_back'}, doStuffWithDom);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) run content scrip after document ready ** check "run_at"

```
"content_scripts": [{
     "run_at": "document_idle",
     "matches"["*://*.google.com/*"],
     "js": ["content.js"]
}],
```

2) on click of extension make another js to run( popup js). The popup js has access to the ( open page document)

```
 // A function to use as callback
    function doStuffWithDom() {
    //console.log('I received the following DOM content:\n' + domContent);
    //get tabID when browser action clicked @ tabId = tab.id
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "js/popup.js"});
    }
```

3) In popup JS simple you can set alert

```
var a = document.getElementById("resultStats");
alert(a.innerText);  // or alert(a.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. but i am facing two issues.

1) popup.js is not executing. i have just added an alert i.e. alert("Hello"); but it is not executing. thus control is not going to popup.js

2) even if i do not go to popup.js and do this directly , 
var a = document.getElementById("resultStats");
alert(a.innerText); 
This is not giving anything though this element exists on google search page

Comment: var a = document.getElementById("resultStats"); returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `"default_popup"` part in `manifest.json`, as you have listened to `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event in background page. They can't live at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. But that did not worked either. :( 
I just want to fetch some text from any webpage and that doesn't work...

Comment: @TechBuddy, please check if the url matches `"*://*.google.com/*"` and `/^https?:\/\/(?:[^./?#]+\.)?google\.com/`. Basically the url may not end with `.com`, it may be some locale string, like `co.jp`.

Comment: The issue that i am facing is document.URL is returning the url for the extension (not of the current Webpage)